# annotate boxplot in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot, geom-text

I've created a side-by-side boxplot using ggplot2.

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=factor(cyl), y=mpg))
p + geom_boxplot(aes(fill=factor(cyl)))
```

I want to annotate with min, max, 1st quartile, median and 3rd quartile in the plot. I know `geom_text()` can do so and may be `fivenum()` is useful. But I cannot figure out how exactly I can do!. These values should be displayed in my plot.

Answer (score 19):

The most succinct way I can think of is to use `stat_summary`. I've also mapped the labels to a color aesthetic, but you can, of course, set the labels to a single color if you wish:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=factor(cyl), y=mpg, fill=factor(cyl))) + 
  geom_boxplot(width=0.6) +
  stat_summary(geom="text", fun.y=quantile,
               aes(label=sprintf("%1.1f", ..y..), color=factor(cyl)),
               position=position_nudge(x=0.33), size=3.5) +
  theme_bw()
```

In the code above we use `quantile` as the summary function to get the label values. `..y..` refers back to the output of the `quantile` function (in general, `..*..` is a ggplot construction for using values calculated within ggplot).

[image]

Comment: Nice answer. While a trivial difference, I am not sure ggplot uses the same fivenum summary - so there may be differences.

Comment: @user20650 (isn't it about time you gave yourself of more distinctive SO name?) doesn't gpplot call whatever function is given in `fun.y`, so wouldn't it just call the `fivenum` function from `stats`?

Comment: As, now I see your point. geom_boxplot is using quantile, but fivenum is using a different algorithm. I've updated my answer to use quantile.

Comment: How to plot uppper and lower whisker numbers on the boxplot as maximum and minimum values? (instead of the outliers numbers). For example for the last boxplot in blue, the minimum and maximum are outliers.

Answer (score 6):

One way is to simply make the data.frame you need, and pass it to `geom_text` or `geom_label`:

```
library(dplyr)

cyl_fivenum <- mtcars %>% 
    group_by(cyl) %>% 
    summarise(five = list(fivenum(mpg))) %>% 
    tidyr::unnest()

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=factor(cyl), y=mpg)) + 
    geom_boxplot(aes(fill=factor(cyl))) + 
    geom_text(data = cyl_fivenum, 
              aes(x = factor(cyl), y = five, label = five), 
              nudge_x = .5)
```

[image: boxplot with labels]

Answer (score 5):

In case anyone is dealing with large ranges and has to log10 transform their y-axis, I found some code that works great. Just add `10^..y..` and `scale_y_log10()`. If you don't add `10^` before `..y..` the actual quantile values will be log transformed and displayed as such.

**Does not work**

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=factor(cyl), y=mpg, fill=factor(cyl))) + 
  geom_boxplot(width=0.6) +
  stat_summary(geom="text", fun.y=quantile,
           aes(label=sprintf("%1.1f", ..y..), color=factor(cyl)),
           position=position_nudge(x=0.45), size=3.5) +
  scale_y_log10()+
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

**Works great**

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=factor(cyl), y=mpg, fill=factor(cyl))) + 
  geom_boxplot(width=0.6) +
  stat_summary(geom="text", fun.y=quantile,
           aes(label=sprintf("%1.1f", 10^..y..), color=factor(cyl)),
           position=position_nudge(x=0.45), size=3.5) +
  scale_y_log10()+
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: I should have scrolled down 15 minutes ago, I've been banging my head against the wall trying to figure out why my values were wrong!

Comment: Glad I could help!