# Labeling Side-By-Side Boxplots

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph

```
sb = as.data.frame(Seatbelts)
sb$law = as.factor(sb$law)
```

```
##THIS CODE WORKS, BUT NO LABELS
RearLaw=subset(sb,law==1)
RearNoLaw=subset(sb,law==0)
ggplot(sb,aes(x=law,y=rear))+geom_boxplot()+labs(x="Seatbelt Laws (1=TRUE)",
y="# of Rear Deaths & Serious Injuries",title="Rear Deaths With & Without Seatbelt Laws")
```

```
##THIS CODE DOESN'T WORK
ggplot(sb,aes(x=law,y=rear))+geom_boxplot()+labs(x="Seatbelt Laws (1=TRUE)",
y="# of Rear Deaths & Serious Injuries",title="Rear Deaths With & Without Seatbelt Laws")+
geom_text(x=boxplot.stats(RearLaw$rear),label=fivenum(RearLaw$rear))
```

I am trying to create side-by-side boxplots with the summary statistics for RearLaw and RearNoLaw displayed next to their respective boxes, but I keep getting the message: "Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (192): x and label". I think this is because fivenum generates 5 outputs and my df has 192 items, but I only want those five to be displayed. The code above includes an attempt at labeling the RearLaw box (ie law=1), but I would like to label the RearNoLaw box as well (law=0) if possible.
I'm entirely new to R and have never posted here, so please let me know if there's any other information to provide.

Comment: @AllanCameron Thx Allan. Hard to knew all of them.

Answer (score 1):

```
cyl_fivenum <- sb %>% 
    group_by(law) %>%
    summarise(five = list(fivenum(rear))) %>% 
    tidyr::unnest()

    ggplot(sb, aes(x = law, y = rear)) +
      geom_boxplot()+
      labs(x="Seatbelt Laws (1=TRUE)",
           y="# of Rear Deaths & Serious Injuries",title="Rear Deaths With & Without Seatbelt Laws") +
      geom_text(data = cyl_fivenum, 
                  aes(x = factor(law), y = five, label = five), 
                  nudge_x = .5)
```

[image]

Comment: This is really a duplicate from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38020772/annotate-boxplot-in-ggplot2?rq=1